# Gammu-smsd - can't send SMS, Error getting security status: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])

Tags: sms, gammu

I have Gammu version 1.42.0 and I can send SMS's succesfully with this command:

> echo "Test" | gammu --sendsms TEXT "+40740...."

and this config file:

```
[gammu]
port = /dev/ttyUSB1
model =
connection = at19200
synchronizetime = yes
logfile = /var/log/gammu.log
logformat = textall
use_locking =
gammuloc =
```

But I can't send SMS's using the gamu-smsd. I have this config file:

```
root@postgresqlsiuiextra:~# cat /etc/gammu-smsdrc
[gammu]
port = /dev/ttyUSB1
model =
connection = at19200
synchronizetime = yes
logfile = /var/log/gammu.log
logformat = textall
use_locking =
gammuloc =

[smsd]
logfile = syslog
debuglevel = 255
service = sql
driver = native_pgsql
Host = 192.168.0.191:5434
User = sms
Password = ****
Database = siui_extra
CheckSecurity = 0 // line to disable checking the security of the phone, there was an error here
receive = False // line to disable the incoming SMS, there was a problem with them
hangupcalls = 1 // line to disable the incoming SMS, there was a problem with them

# Paths where messages are stored
inboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/inbox/
outboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/outbox/
sentsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/sent/
errorsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/error/
```

And I launch like this and I have this errors :

```
root@postgresqlsiuiextra:/etc# gammu-smsd -c /etc/gammu-smsdrc
gammu-smsd[14974]: Error getting security status: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])
gammu-smsd[14974]: You might want to set CheckSecurity = 0 to avoid checking security status
gammu-smsd[14974]: Error getting security status: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])
gammu-smsd[14974]: You might want to set CheckSecurity = 0 to avoid checking security status
gammu-smsd[14974]: Error getting security status: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])
gammu-smsd[14974]: You might want to set CheckSecurity = 0 to avoid checking security status
gammu-smsd[14974]: Error getting security status: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])
gammu-smsd[14974]: You might want to set CheckSecurity = 0 to avoid checking security status
gammu-smsd[14974]: Error getting security status: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])
gammu-smsd[14974]: You might want to set CheckSecurity = 0 to avoid checking security status
gammu-smsd[14974]: Error getting security status: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])
gammu-smsd[14974]: You might want to set CheckSecurity = 0 to avoid checking security status
```

In /var/log/syslog I have a lot of logs because of the debug info, it starts like this:

```
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Using SQL service
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Configuring Gammu SMSD...
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: SHM token: 0x1020733 (16910131)
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Warning: No PIN code in /etc/gammu-smsdrc file
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: CommTimeout=30, SendTimeout=30, ReceiveFrequency=15, ResetFrequency=0, HardResetFrequency=0
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: checks: CheckSecurity=1, CheckBattery=1, CheckSignal=1, CheckNetwork=1
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: mode: Send=1, Receive=1
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: deliveryreport = no
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: phoneid =
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Connected to database: siui_extra on 192.168.0.191. Server version: 140010 Protocol: 3
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Execute SQL: SELECT  * FROM gammu  LIMIT 1
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Execute SQL: SELECT  * FROM inbox  LIMIT 1
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Execute SQL: SELECT  * FROM sentitems  LIMIT 1
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Execute SQL: SELECT  * FROM outbox  LIMIT 1
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Execute SQL: SELECT  * FROM outbox_multipart  LIMIT 1
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Execute SQL: SELECT  * FROM phones  LIMIT 1
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Execute SQL: SELECT "Version" FROM gammu
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Database structures version: 17, SMSD current version: 17
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Connected to Database native_pgsql: siui_extra on 192.168.0.191
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Created POSIX RW shared memory at 0x7f6d602b7000
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Starting phone communication...
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: [Gammu            - 1.42.0]
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: [Connection       - "at19200"]
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: [Connection index - 0]
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: [Model type       - ""]
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: [Device           - "/dev/ttyUSB1"]
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: [Running on       - Linux, kernel 5.15.0-94-generic (#104-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 15:25:40 UTC 2024)]
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Serial device: DTR is down, RTS is down, CAR is down, CTS is down
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Setting DTR failed, disabling setting of DTR/RTS signals.
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Setting RTS failed, disabling setting of DTR/RTS signals.
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: [Module           - "auto"]
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Escaping SMS mode
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x02/2
Feb 13 09:14:47 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1B |0D                                                          ..
Feb 13 09:14:48 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Sending simple AT command to wake up some devices
Feb 13 09:14:48 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x03/3
Feb 13 09:14:48 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|0D                                                      AT.
Feb 13 09:14:48 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "AT"
Feb 13 09:14:48 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "OK"
Feb 13 09:14:48 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: OK
Feb 13 09:14:48 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 1
Feb 13 09:14:48 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x09/9
Feb 13 09:14:48 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                              AT...OK..
Feb 13 09:14:48 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Enabling echo
Feb 13 09:14:48 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x05/5
Feb 13 09:14:48 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|45E|311|0D                                              ATE1.
Feb 13 09:14:49 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "ATE1"
Feb 13 09:14:49 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "OK"
Feb 13 09:14:49 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: OK
Feb 13 09:14:49 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 1
Feb 13 09:14:49 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x0B/11
Feb 13 09:14:49 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|45E|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                      ATE1...OK..
Feb 13 09:14:49 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Trying Motorola mode switch
Feb 13 09:14:49 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0A/10
Feb 13 09:14:49 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D                          AT+MODE=2.
```

and ends like this:

```
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|4DM|45E AT+MODE=2...+CME
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 20 |45E|52R|52R|4FO|52R|3A:|20 |311|300|300|0D |0A               ERROR: 100..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: CME Error 100: "unknown"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Seems not to be supported
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Enabling CME errors
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0A/10
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D                          AT+CMEE=1.
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "AT+CMEE=1"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "OK"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: OK
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 1
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x10/16
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CMEE=1...OK..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x09/9
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "AT+CSCS?"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "+CSCS: "HEX""
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 3 "OK"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: OK
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 1
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x1F/31
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S AT+CSCS?...+CSCS
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 3A:|20 |22"|48H|45E|58X|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : "HEX"....OK..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0A/10
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D                          AT+CSCS=?.
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "AT+CSCS=?"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "+CSCS: ("IRA", "GSM", "HEX", "PCCP437", "8859-1", "UCS2", "UCS2_0X81")"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 3 "OK"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: OK
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 1
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x5A/90
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C AT+CSCS=?...+CSC
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 53S|3A:|20 |28(|22"|49I|52R|41A|22"|2C,|20 |22"|47G|53S|4DM|22" S: ("IRA", "GSM"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2C,|20 |22"|48H|45E|58X|22"|2C,|20 |22"|50P|43C|43C|50P|344|333 , "HEX", "PCCP43
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 377|22"|2C,|20 |22"|388|388|355|399|2D-|311|22"|2C,|20 |22"|55U 7", "8859-1", "U
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 43C|53S|322|22"|2C,|20 |22"|55U|43C|53S|322|5F_|300|58X|388|311 CS2", "UCS2_0X81
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 22"|29)|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                          ")....OK..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Chosen HEX as normal charset
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Chosen UCS2 as unicode charset
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x08/8
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D                                  AT+CGMI.
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "AT+CGMI"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "+CME ERROR: 100"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: +CME ERROR: 100
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 6
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x1B/27
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|4DM|45E|20 |45E AT+CGMI...+CME E
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 52R|52R|4FO|52R|3A:|20 |311|300|300|0D |0A                      RROR: 100..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: CME Error 100: "unknown"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x05/5
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|49I|333|0D                                              ATI3.
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "ATI3"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "MTK2"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 3 "PISCES.11.02.11.p1"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 4 "OK"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: OK
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 1
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x27/39
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|49I|333|0D |0D |0A |4DM|54T|4BK|322|0D |0A |50P|49I|53S ATI3...MTK2..PIS
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 43C|45E|53S|2E.|311|311|2E.|300|322|2E.|311|311|2E.|70p|311|0D  CES.11.02.11.p1.
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                      ...OK..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Manufacturer info received
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: [Manufacturer: MTK2]
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking for OBEX support
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0B/11
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D                      AT+CPROT=?.
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "AT+CPROT=?"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "+CME ERROR: 100"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: +CME ERROR: 100
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 6
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x1E/30
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|4DM AT+CPROT=?...+CM
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 45E|20 |45E|52R|52R|4FO|52R|3A:|20 |311|300|300|0D |0A          E ERROR: 100..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: CME Error 100: "unknown"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking for SYNCML/OBEX support
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0C/12
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D                  AT+SYNCML=?.
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "AT+SYNCML=?"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "+CME ERROR: 100"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: +CME ERROR: 100
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 6
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x1F/31
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C AT+SYNCML=?...+C
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 4DM|45E|20 |45E|52R|52R|4FO|52R|3A:|20 |311|300|300|0D |0A      ME ERROR: 100..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: CME Error 100: "unknown"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0D/13
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D              AT$TSSPCSW=?.
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "AT$TSSPCSW=?"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "+CME ERROR: 100"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: +CME ERROR: 100
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 6
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x20/32
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+ AT$TSSPCSW=?...+
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 43C|4DM|45E|20 |45E|52R|52R|4FO|52R|3A:|20 |311|300|300|0D |0A  CME ERROR: 100..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: CME Error 100: "unknown"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0A/10
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|48H|55U|50P|3D=|3F?|0D                          AT+CHUP=?.
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "AT+CHUP=?"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "OK"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: OK
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 1
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x10/16
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|48H|55U|50P|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CHUP=?...OK..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Setting date & time
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x1F/31
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|43C|4CL|4BK|3D=|22"|322|344|2F/|300|322|2F/|311 AT+CCLK="24/02/1
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 333|2C,|300|399|3A:|311|355|3A:|322|399|2B+|300|322|22"|0D      3,09:15:29+02".
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "AT+CCLK="24/02/13,09:15:29+02""
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "ERROR"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: ERROR
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 3
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x28/40
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|43C|4CL|4BK|3D=|22"|322|344|2F/|300|322|2F/|311 AT+CCLK="24/02/1
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 333|2C,|300|399|3A:|311|355|3A:|322|399|2B+|300|322|22"|0D |0D  3,09:15:29+02"..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 0A |45E|52R|52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                  .ERROR..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Getting firmware versions
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x08/8
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|52R|0D                                  AT+CGMR.
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "AT+CGMR"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "+CGMR: PISCES.11.02.11.p1, 2020/03/04 12:13"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 3 "OK"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: OK
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 1
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x3D/61
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|52R|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|47G|4DM|52R|3A: AT+CGMR...+CGMR:
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 20 |50P|49I|53S|43C|45E|53S|2E.|311|311|2E.|300|322|2E.|311|311  PISCES.11.02.11
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2E.|70p|311|2C,|20 |322|300|322|300|2F/|300|333|2F/|300|344|20  .p1, 2020/03/04
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 311|322|3A:|311|333|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A              12:13....OK..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Received firmware version: "PISCES.11.02.11.p1, 2020/03/04 12:13"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Number version is "0.110211"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: [Firmware version - "PISCES.11.02.11.p1, 2020/03/04 12:13"]
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Set AT phone power on
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0A/10
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|46F|55U|4EN|3D=|311|0D                          AT+CFUN=1.
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "AT+CFUN=1"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "OK"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: OK
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 1
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x10/16
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|46F|55U|4EN|3D=|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CFUN=1...OK..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: [Connected]
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Entering GSM_GetSecurityStatus
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Getting security code status
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x09/9
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|49I|4EN|3F?|0D                              AT+CPIN?.
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 1 "AT+CPIN?"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 2 "+CME ERROR: 100"
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Checking line: +CME ERROR: 100
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: AT reply state: 6
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x1C/28
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|49I|4EN|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|4DM|45E|20  AT+CPIN?...+CME
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: 45E|52R|52R|4FO|52R|3A:|20 |311|300|300|0D |0A                  ERROR: 100..
Feb 13 09:15:29 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: CME Error 100: "unknown"
Feb 13 09:15:30 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: GSM_GetSecurityStatus failed with error UNKNOWN[27]: Unknown error.
Feb 13 09:15:30 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: Leaving GSM_GetSecurityStatus
Feb 13 09:15:30 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Error getting security status: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])
Feb 13 09:15:30 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: You might want to set CheckSecurity = 0 to avoid checking security status
Feb 13 09:15:30 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Already hit 2 errors
Feb 13 09:15:30 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Terminating communication: No error. (NONE[1])
Feb 13 09:15:30 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: [Terminating]
Feb 13 09:15:30 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: gammu: [Closing]
Feb 13 09:15:30 postgresqlsiuiextra gammu-smsd[15026]: Going to 30 seconds sleep because of too many connection errors
```

I do not need to receive SMSs, I only need to send them.

The output of gammu identify:

```
root@postgresqlsiuiextra:~# gammu identify
Device               : /dev/ttyUSB1
Manufacturer         : MTK2
Model                : MTK2 (MTK2)
Firmware             : PISCES.11.02.11.p1, 2020/03/04 12:13
SIM IMSI             : 226101201415218
```

The phone is a "Nokia 5310 (2020)" and I use it because this is the second phone I bought and the first worked with the same version on Gammu. I tried to move the SIM from one phone to the other but both phones fail on the new server.

I just don't understand why I can send SMSs from the command line but I cant send them from gammu-smsd, I guess gammu-smsd used some extended functionality and it fails... but I tried  to disable all other functions except from sending SMSs with these lines:

```
 CheckSecurity = 0 // line to disable checking the security of the phone, there was an error here
    receive = False // line to disable the incoming SMS, there was a problem with them
    hangupcalls = 1 // line to disable the incoming SMS, there was a problem with them
```

but gammu sems to ignore them.

I inject SMSs directly from SQL like this:

> INSERT INTO smsd.outbox
> ("DestinationNumber","TextDecoded","CreatorID","Coding") VALUES
> ('40740863629','CAS Test','1','Default_No_Compression');

I already hav e a full day of Chat GPT  with no success so here I am. :)

**LATER EDIT** I removed the SIM PIN and the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem after downloading the Gammu source code... is acctually very simple, these lines:

```
CheckSecurity = 0 // line to disable checking the security of the phone, there was an error here
receive = False // line to disable the incoming SMS, there was a problem with them
hangupcalls = 1 // line to disable the incoming SMS, there was a problem with them
```

are not correctly read by Gammu because Gammu config files do not support comments. So with my original phone that worked from the start I had no comments but after seeing it work I thought to write some documentation so as not to forget what I've done. :) But in the docs I added some comments...